# "That was too Easy." phrase

Tags: phrase

Very simple, the phrase is a sort of mocking one that you would say to someone else, implying that it was no challenge to you at all. Example, a friend challenges you to a game of chess and you win rather easily,

Comment: I am not sure what is your question, but if you are asking for translation, you could say 小菜一碟。

Answer (score 3):

“That was too Easy.”  can simply be translated as "那也太容易了"

However, in a mocking manner, you can say:

不外如是 (It is unimpressive)-- *It is a very insulting phrase, saying that is to look down upon someone*

這就完了? (just like this, you are finished?) --*implying the other guy cannot provide tougher challenge to you*

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way would be:

> 太简单了

A more local way might just to say something like:

> 不至于吧

This expresses more astonishment as in, "no way!" but it's used a lot of times when people just find something way too easy.

Answer (score 1):

小菜一碟

a can of corn, a piece of cake

Answer (score 0):

There is always 得來全不費功夫... if you want to abuse the meaning of chengyu...

Comment: 踏破鐵鞋無覓處，得來全不費功夫-- you have to work very hard for a long tome before you eventually get a break

Comment: But the chengyu was really about "I've been looking everywhere and it was beside me all along"

Comment: If you notice it is beside you right away, then there's no need for the first part. The whole idiom is describing how satisfying one feels  at the end of a long hard search

Comment: No it wasn't. Quoting from Zdic "比喻平日有心求之而不得，忽一朝無意而得之。"  The chenyu is about the surprise, not the satisfaction. https://www.zdic.net/hant/%E8%B8%8F%E7%A0%B4%E9%90%B5%E9%9E%8B%E7%84%A1%E8%A6%93%E8%99%95%EF%BC%8C%E5%BE%97%E4%BE%86%E5%85%A8%E4%B8%8D%E8%B2%BB%E5%8A%9F%E5%A4%AB#:~:text=%E8%B8%8F%E7%A0%B4%E9%90%B5%E9%9E%8B%E7%84%A1%E8%A6%93%E8%99%95%EF%BC%8C%E5%BE%97%E4%BE%86%E5%85%A8%E4%B8%8D,%E4%BE%86%E5%85%A8%E4%B8%8D%E8%B2%BB%E5%B7%A5%E5%A4%AB%EF%BC%81%E2%80%9D